# How to work with SignalR in ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, signalr

We're working on an asp.net core project that depends on SignalR. Lastly we updated our project from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0 and SignalR stopped working. In the documentation we configured everything (I think correctly) but is still doesn't work. What did we miss?

**ASP.NET Core 3.0 API**

Startup:

```
public class Startup
{
     private readonly string corsPolicy = "CorsPolicy";
     private static string[] AllowdOrigins() => return new string[] {"localhost:4200","example.com"};

     public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
     {
         Configuration = configuration;
     }

     public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
            ConfigureAuthentication(services);

            ///MICROSOFT SQL DATABASE
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
            ));

            services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
            });

            services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("XX.XX.XX.XX"));
            });

            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddControllers();

            //services dependencies
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors(corsPolicy);

            //app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            //{
            //    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            //});

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat");
            });

            DummyData.Initialize(app);
        }

        private void ConfigureAuthentication(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(corsPolicy,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .WithOrigins(AllowdOrigins());
                });
            });

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            // configure strongly typed settings objects
            var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

            // configure jwt authentication
            var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);

            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
        }
}
```

Chathub:

```
[EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    private static Dictionary<string, int> onlineClientCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    private static readonly string FrontPrefix = "_FRONT";

    public ChatHub()
    {
    }

    [HubMethodName("ConnectFrontend")]
    public async Task ConnectFrontend(int sessionId)
    {
        //////
    }

    [HubMethodName("ConnectDevice")]
    public async Task ConnectDevice(int sessionId)
    {
        //// This method should be called but it isn't.
    }

    public void DisConnect(int sessionId, int userId)
    {
       //////////
    }

    [HubMethodName("SendJsonToFrontends")]
    public async Task SendJsonToFrontends(int sessionId, string jsonString)
    {
        ///
    }

    [HubMethodName("SendJsonToAll")]
    public async Task SendJsonToAll(int sessionId, string jsonString)
    {
         ////
    }
}
```

**Angular project**

`SignalRService`:

```
export class SignalRService {

  private connection: signalR.HubConnection;

  public newMessage = new Subject<SocketMessage>();

  constructor() {
    
  }

  public connectFront() {

    this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("http://localhost:2525/chat")//(environment.baseSignalR)
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Trace)
        .build();


    this.connection.on("ReceiveJson", data => { this.handleJsonMessage(data) });

    // handles the first connection message
    this.connection.start().then(() => this.sendConnectionMessage());

    // handles the incoming messages
    this.connection.on("ReceiveJson", data => this.handleJsonMessage(data));
    this.connection.on("ReceiveJsonFrontend", data => this.handleJsonMessage(data));
  }

  private sendConnectionMessage() {
    var sessionId = sessionStorage.getItem("SessionId");
    if (sessionId != null) {
        this.connection.invoke("ConnectFrontend", sessionId).catch((error) => { debugger; console.log(error); });
    }
  }

  public sendWebsocketMessageToAll(msg: SocketMessage) {
    var sessionId = sessionStorage.getItem("SessionId");
    if (sessionId != null) {
      this.connection.invoke("SendJsonToAll", sessionId, JSON.stringify(msg)).catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }
  }

  public sendWebsocketMessageToFrontend(msg: SocketMessage) {
    var sessionId = sessionStorage.getItem("SessionId");
    if (sessionId != null) {
      this.connection.invoke("SendJsonToFrontends", sessionId, JSON.stringify(msg)).catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }
  }

  private handleJsonMessage(data: string) {
    this.newMessage.next(this.getSocketMessage(data));
  }

  public getSocketMessage(data: string): SocketMessage {
    var msg: SocketMessage = JSON.parse(data);
    return msg;
  }

  public disconnect() {
    this.connection.stop();
  }
}
```

angular output:
[image]

Api output:
[image]

Comment: Do you get any error in console? You will need to upgrade the angular SignalR package too to 3.0 version if you haven't already.

Comment: This may help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#signalr-1

Comment: I've updated my question with the console logs

Comment: I can't find a package that includes 3.0 the last version of nuget SignalR is 1.1.0

Comment: On angular side I've updated @aspnet/angular to @microsoft/angular 3.0.0 but still the error continues

Comment: As the client error, there is something wrong in your server side. Did you get any error in the server side? Does `ConnectFrontend` hit at server side?

Comment: Any update on this ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm working on this problem only on tuesday and thursday. I'll try everyting tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Just create an web app API with angular template you can view my code for your ref

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
        services.AddSignalR().AddJsonProtocol(options =>
        {
            options.PayloadSerializerOptions.WriteIndented = false;
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
```

In FE side. Note: use new package [@microsoft/signalr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr)

```
import * as signalR from "@microsoft/signalr";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'app';

    ngOnInit() {
        const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("/chathub")
            .build();

        connection.on("receiveMessage", (username: string, message: string) => {
            console.log(username);
            console.log(message);
        });

        connection.start().then(() => {
            connection.send("sendMessage", "aaa", "aaaa")
                .then(() => console.log("done"));

        }).catch(err => document.write(err));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I finaly figured it out with the help of Tony,

Apperently It went wrong in the methods of the SignalR chat hub. The methods allowed only integers as parameters but it needed to be strings. I don't know it it has to do with some other settings but my guess now is that signalr cant convert the request parameters to something other then strings.

When I changed it to strings it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you have configured JWT based authentication on the server side and do not provide a token for SignalR connection. Try to provide a token using the accessTokenFactory:

```
this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(`${environment.urlAddress}/chathub`, {
                accessTokenFactory: () => this.token
            })
            .build()
```